# jersey restful webservice resource not found error

Tags: java, hibernate, web-services, rest, maven

i m making a signup page using jersey restful webservice + hibernate framework and maven java project.
Registration class:

```
package com.data;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
@Entity
public class Registration {

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
private String fristName;
private String lastName;
private String email;
private String password;
private String rePassword;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getFristName() {
    return fristName;
}
public void setFristName(String fristName) {
    this.fristName = fristName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public String getRePassword() {
    return rePassword;
}
public void setRePassword(String rePassword) {
    this.rePassword = rePassword;
}
}
```

RegistrationService Class:

```
package com.dao;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import com.data.Registration;
public class RegistrationService {

private SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;

public Registration adddNewUser(Registration newUser){

    try{
        sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(newUser);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return newUser;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public ArrayList<Registration> getUsers(){
    ArrayList<Registration> users = new ArrayList<Registration>();
    try{
        sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        users = (ArrayList<Registration>) session.createCriteria(Registration.class).list();
        session.close();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return users;
}
}
```

RegistrationResource Class:

```
    package com.resource;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import com.dao.RegistrationService;
import com.data.Registration;
@Path("register")
public class RegistrationResource {

private RegistrationService registrationService = new RegistrationService();

@Path("new")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Registration addNewUser(Registration newUser){
    return registrationService.adddNewUser(newUser);
}   

@GET
@Path("all")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ArrayList<Registration> getAllUsers(){
    return registrationService.getUsers();
}
}
```

Someone help .......
kindly someone tell me where is problem i will be thankful to u... :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using Maven and pom as a build mechanishm for building your application.If your restful service is a web application,then you need to map restful property in web.xml ,otherwise the jersey server won't be able to find the resource:

```
 <servlet>
            <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
                <param-value>com.resource</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
                <param-value>true</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>


    <!-- Servlet Mappings -->
            <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/register/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: i m checking on postman rest client one method that jersey make when project is created is working good the other method that i make is not working

Comment: Could you please tell me which method is not working??

Comment: Just looking at your code it seems to me that the following method is not working: public ArrayList<Registration> getAllUsers(){
    return registrationService.getUsers();
}
 as jersey dont allow you to send arrayList of object by default.You need to modify the default ContextResolver or Messagebodywriter inorder to do that. Another thing that you can do is to wrap your ArrayList<Registration> inside a javax.ws.rs.core.GenericEntity and return GenericEntity<List<Registration>>(registrationService.getUsers()).